# How can I redirect to a specific route from a children using beforeEnter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, children

According to the route configuration below, my application should redirect to '/login' if the user is not authenticated :

```js
const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if(Store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    next({ path: '/login' });
  }
}

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: DsLogin
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: DsHome,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        ifAuthenticated(to, from, next);
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/other',
      name: 'other',
      component: DsOther,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        ifAuthenticated(to, from, next);
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/demand-history',
      name: 'demand history',
      component: DsDemandHistory,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        ifAuthenticated(to, from, next);
      },
      redirect: '/demand-history/1/all/all/all',
      children: [
        {
          path: ':page/:type/:state/:owner',
          name: 'demand history filtered',
          props: true,
          beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            ifAuthenticated(to, from, next);
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

It works well when i'm navigating to path '/' or '/other'.
But when i'm navigating to the path '/demand-history/1/all/all/all', I get redirected to '/demand-history/1/all/all/login'

using `next({ name: 'Login' })` does not work either

How should I manage to get redirect to '/login' as well ?

Thx

Comment: Your redirect lacks a "/" at the begining. Also, as a tip, for function guards, you can directly pass your ifAuthenticated like so ```beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated```. Finally, your beforeEnter guard on the parent route has not effect since it redirects.

Comment: I corrected the lacks of '/'.

the code is the simplified version of the configuration, that's why i call ifAuthenticated this way.

It looks like the beforeEnter is call even if there is a redirect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection was not initiate by the method `ifAuthenticated` but upstream in my code.

An Interceptor caught a 401 error and redirect to login using `Router.push('login')`

Altering the code with `Router.push({ name: 'Login' })` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the name of that route `return {name: 'Login'}`.

P.S. The names of your other routes are all lowercase except `Login` so maybe anyone reading this can recheck their route names.